# How do I get synonyms in SQL Server FreeTextTable() searches?

Tags: sql-server, freetext, freetexttable

I did a search for "GLBT" where the text in the DB has "LGBT+" in it. It did not return any rows. Same for doing a search on "cars" when the DB has "vehicles" in it.

Isn't FreeTextTable supposed to find synonyms? Or do I need to do something additional for it to find matches based on synonyms?

Comment: You need to configure Thesaurus Files for Full-Text Search have a look at this article [`Configure and Manage Thesaurus Files for Full-Text Search`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-thesaurus-files-for-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: SQL Server can't possibly know that GLBT and LGBT+ are synonyms. How could it? Because they contain the same letters? Should it also think that TPS and STP are synonyms? Are VIP and MVP "close"? Similarly, the engine doesn't know what a car is, never mind that it is a type of vehicle. You need to tell it how to make these associations. (By default, it supports stemmers - different forms of a verb or single/plural of a noun.)

Comment: @M.Ali First, thank you. Second, is there a default English thesaurus that is available for us? Creating my own thesaurus would be a gigantic effort. TIA

Comment: I don't think Microsoft ever delivered a more comprehensive thesaurus file, but you can try out some from 3rd parties, like [this one](http://thinknook.com/sql-server-english-thesaurus-for-fulltext-search-2012-02-07/). I think it's a gigantic effort to create some all-encompassing English thesaurus because things that are synonyms for your application (or even for different FT indexes on the same instance, since they share a single thesaurus) might be very different from mine. I might prioritize `java` -> `coffee`, for example, while you prioritize `java` -> `jdbc`.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 Thank you. If you post that as an answer, happy to accept it. And by definition any general purpose (my use case) thesaurus is going to not be perfect. But it beats not having one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SQL Server supports stemmers - different forms of a verb or single/plural of a noun. It does not (and can't!) natively know that car is a type of vehicle, for example, or that one acronym is a synonym for another.

Ages ago, Microsoft promised a more comprehensive thesaurus file, but I don't think they have ever delivered one.

You can try out some from 3rd parties, like [this one](http://thinknook.com/sql-server-english-thesaurus-for-fulltext-search-2012-02-07/). I think it would be a gigantic effort to create some all-encompassing English thesaurus that suits everyone, because things that are synonyms for your application (or even for different FT indexes on the same instance, since they share a single thesaurus) might be very different from, say, mine. I might prioritize `java` -> `coffee`, for example, while you might prioritize `java` -> `jdbc`.